# Firefox extension to queue links instead of opening in tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there an extension that I can use to queue links instead of opening them all in tabs? I'd like to reduce my memory usage and realistically I would like to load on demand.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to try the [Link Queue & Preview Sidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-queue-preview-sidebar/) extension. You'll have to look through the options and might not want to use the preview function but it should do what you want.

Comment: Looks like it's not good for 5.""